# Custom Command for command line for invoking java class

Tags: java, command-line

I would like to make a custom command, which can invoke my java class. I am not sure how to proceed with it.

I don't want to use java < classname> instead I want to create a custom command say mycmd which would run the java class.

Comment: java <classname> won't work ?

Comment: I don't want to use java <classname> instead I want to use a command say mycmd which would run the java class.

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Are you using bash? Linux? Windows? etc. Why not just create a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon which OS you're working on, you can always create either batch(.bat for windows) or shell(.sh for unix/linux/mac etc). Pass class name as parameter. Call java command under the script with passed classname.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a file called mycmd that has a single line with:

java classname

then run the file by typing mycmd at the command line.